# Skip all databases and run only specific one

Tags: database, linux, mysql

I have a sql file generated by "mysqldump --all-databases" . There are many databases in it. What I want to do is to update my local database but only a specific one, not all. I tried to use "mysql -database=db_name < file.sql" but it updated all databases. Is there a way to skip all databases except the one that I want.

Comment: You'll have more luck on serverfault.com (odds are this question will get migrated by users pretty quickly, I've kicked things off).

Comment: @Ergec: See my answer edit. I don't know what happened when you used codeaddict's solution, but the `-D` solution simply *does not do* what that answer says it does.

Comment: not -D but -o (--one-database) did it

Comment: You are **absolutely** right. With the `-o` option, this works as expected. That's fantastic! I've updated codaddict's answer to emphasize that, and will remove comments saying it doesn't work except the one above (so your reply and this reply don't seem strange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
mysql -D example_database -o < dump.sql
```

This will only execute the `SQL` commands for the specified database and will skip the commands for all other databases. The [`-o` ("one database") option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database) is *critical* to this working as expected (it tells `mysql` to ignore statements related to other databases).

`dump.sql` is the result of executing `mysqldump --all-databases`

Comment: `mysql -D foo` is the same as `mysql --database=foo` which "updated all databases"

Comment: Nice one, sorry I missed the `-o` option earlier!

Answer (score 0):

*it's getting dirty, stop reading if or be warned ;)*

It's not pretty and maybe there is a better (correct) way to achive this. But assuming the dumps you are working with aren't to big, you might be quicker by importing the full dump into temporary DBs and creating a fresh dump of the database you'd like to import. (As I said, not pretty)

Additionally, you should really make sure that you're able to restore backups you make (in any imaginable way). This could get *really* embarrassing the day you need them urgently.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

1. You can edit the dump file (it's just a text file, after all), extracting only the items related to the database you want to restore. I think each database is written to the file individually, so this is a matter of identifying the one big block related to the one you want and deleting the bits before and after it -- e.g., not as much of a chore as it sounds. Look for the `create database` and `use` statements (there's also -- at least in my version, with my options) a banner comment "Current Database: `foo`" at the top of each section). This would be pretty easy to do with `vi` or anything else that lets you do large operations easily. You can then search through the result ensuring that there are no cross-references to the DBs you don't want updated.
2. You can back up the databases you don't want updated, do the update, then restore them. I mean, before you do this sort of thing, you have a backup anyway, right? ;-)
3. You can restore to a blank MySQL instance, then grab the backup of the one you want. Blech.
4. (Variation on #3) You can do a rename on all of your current databases, import the file, then drop the ones you don't want and rename the originals back. Also blech.

I'd probably go with #1 (after a full backup). Good luck with it.

**Edit** No, I'd go with [codaddict's `-D databasename -o` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407981/skip-all-databases-and-run-only-specific-one/2408033#2408033) (after a full backup). *Nice one*

Comment: Hi, I don't know why you deleted other answers but "mysql -D dbname -o < file.sql" did it. I tried it several times with and without "-o" and yes it skips the other databases.

Comment: @Ergec: Crowder did not del it. I dit it :), I've put it back. Good to know it works.

Comment: @Crowder I think you are missing -o (--one-database)

Comment: @Ergec: I was indeed! See my comment on your question above. Thanks for letting me know!